# Узнать только часть строки (регулярные выражения)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть строка 
`<option value="1" data-code2="AF">AF - Afghanistan</option>`.

Из неё требуется вырезать только `AF`.

С регулярками никогда не сталкивался, поэтому прошу Вашей помощи.

Comment: А зачем Вы из селекта таким образом берете данные? расскажите подробнее про Вашу задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример регулярного выражения

```
$text='<option value="1" data-code2="AF">AF - Afghanistan</option>';
```

попроще

```
$regexp='/"(\w\w)"/ui';

$match = [];
    if (preg_match($regexp, $text, $match)){
        print_r($match[1]);
    }
```

чуть посложнее

```
$regexp='/data-\w+="(\w\w)"/ui';

$match = [];
    if (preg_match($regexp, $text, $match)){
        print_r($match[1]);
    }
```

Если нужно получить все вхождения, то следует использовать match_all. Регулярное выражение не поменяется.

```
$match = [];
    if (preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $match)){
        print_r($match[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, подошло, теперь стоит задача посложнее. Записей несколько: `                                                                            <option value="1" data-code2="AF">AF - Afghanistan</option>
                                                                            <option value="2" data-code2="AX">AX - Aland Islands</option>` И у каждого последовательно нужно обрезать только эти два символа, подскажите?

Comment: Добавил в ответ.